# What is the meaning of this line?

Tags: java

I am looking at a sample game project. Can you explain these lines:

```
public static final int GAMEPAD_UP = 0x0040;
```

What is the use of `0x0040;`?

This is the full code:

```
package com.androidemu;

public class Emulator {
    public static final int VIDEO_W = 240;
    public static final int VIDEO_H = 160;

    public static final int GAMEPAD_UP        = 0x0040;
    public static final int GAMEPAD_DOWN    = 0x0080;
    public static final int GAMEPAD_LEFT    = 0x0020;
    public static final int GAMEPAD_RIGHT    = 0x0010;
    public static final int GAMEPAD_A        = 0x0001;
    public static final int GAMEPAD_B        = 0x0002;
    public static final int GAMEPAD_SELECT    = 0x0004;
    public static final int GAMEPAD_START    = 0x0008;
    public static final int GAMEPAD_TL        = 0x0200;
    public static final int GAMEPAD_TR        = 0x0100;

    public static final int GAMEPAD_A_TURBO    = (GAMEPAD_A << 16);
    public static final int GAMEPAD_B_TURBO    = (GAMEPAD_B << 16);

    public static final int GAMEPAD_UP_LEFT = (GAMEPAD_UP | GAMEPAD_LEFT);
    public static final int GAMEPAD_UP_RIGHT = (GAMEPAD_UP | GAMEPAD_RIGHT);
    public static final int GAMEPAD_DOWN_LEFT = (GAMEPAD_DOWN | GAMEPAD_LEFT);
    public static final int GAMEPAD_DOWN_RIGHT = (GAMEPAD_DOWN | GAMEPAD_RIGHT);

    public native void setRenderSurface(EmulatorView surface,
            int width, int height);
    public native void setKeyStates(int states);
    public native void setOption(String name, String value);

    public native boolean initialize(String libdir, String datadir);
    public native void cleanUp();
    public native void reset();
    public native void power();
    public native boolean loadBIOS(String file);
    public native boolean loadROM(String file);
    public native void unloadROM();
    public native void pause();
    public native void resume();
    public native void run();
    public native boolean saveState(String file);
    public native boolean loadState(String file);

    public void setOption(String name, boolean value) {
        setOption(name, value ? "true" : "false");
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("gba");
    }
}
```

What are the purpose of these values?

Comment: I came across an interesting `double MAX_VALUE = 0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023` the other day.  You are never too old to come across something new. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: see my answer, the question is actually not that silly at all ;)

Comment: What i don't understand is why people vote up questions like these.

Answer (score 11):

It's a value that has exactly one bit set:

```
00000000000000000000000001000000
```

So you can also have, say, `GAMEPAD_RIGHT=0x0010` and you can OR both value and test for any of them indivuadlly by AND'ing.  It is very common in games, especially on mobile devices.

The purpose of such coding is to optimize space and to be able to test various cases in one line.

By using one bit for, say, every possible gamepad key, you can represent on one int (even on one byte in the old 8-bit console days, where console have very few keys) the state of each key (it's either 'on' or 'off').

UP + RIGHT, with both key pressed, gives:

```
00000000000000000000000001000000

               OR

00000000000000000000000000010000

               =

00000000000000000000000001010000
```

Comment: Contrarily to all the others I didn't need your edit to understand what this was about, just the line GAMEPAD_UP=0x0040 was enough of an hint (pun !) to see what this was about ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static final int GAMEPAD_UP = 0x0040;

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.print(GAMEPAD_UP);

}


 Output: 64
```

0x0040 is hexadecimanl(base 16) representation of 64(base 10).

Answer (score 0):

This is definition of an integer constant with hex value `0x0040`.

Comment: Without any other context you can't say much more :) Sure, you can guess.

Answer (score -3):

The concept is, that line assigns the ASCII code for the variable GAMEPAD_UP. Which means when the keyup event is occured afterwards you could find the source of this event inside the eventHandler(source) method.

And according to the source you will make changes in the gameplay. ;)

Comment: Errr, no, it has nothing to do with ASCII codes. It defines a *flag* that is later used to identify a `GAMEPAD_UP` key event.

Comment: hey i still think its the ASCII code that is actually emitted from the GAME PAD when the particular key is activated or pressed. Coz i wrote a game code in C language to move a ball within the screen using the arrow keys. We(coders) usually assign the ASCII code of the expected keyvalue. Since it is going to be checked later inside the event handler, it is a kind of flag too. Why so serious @Andreas_D...

Comment: you mean key codes, they are not the same as ASCII. Besides, the constants in the example are 16 bits and ASCII is only 7 bits.